# Eclipse - error mark in app engine project. Entity not visible in datastore viewer

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

After adding a new entity class to my appengine project, I generated endpoint class and then endpoint library in client project.But soon my appengine project folder in eclipse workspace started displaying error mark.But on expanding the folder,I can not see the exact location of the error.

Also, the entity class is not displayed in the local datastore viewer. What is the reason of error,and why the entity class is not displayed in datastore viewer?

Comment: More information would be needed to determine what is wrong. It sounds like you have an error in your code, but without knowing the code in question and what the error says it is impossible to help. The datastore viewer will not show anything until you actually write an entity - merely having a code class doesn't populate the database.